# Maven : How to compare sub-modules of two modules of a mult-module project?

Tags: maven, module, maven-dependency-plugin

I have a multi-module project that has two modules A and B. Both have their own modules, here on refered as sub-modules.

I want to do some comparison between both types of modules. For example, I want to check that all sub-modules of A should have an associated sub-module in B. How can I do that?

I looked into maven-enforcer-plugin, but I only found examples of managing plugins and dependencies, not modules.

So far, I have been able to print out list of sub-modules of A using following command from [this link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3662291/how-to-list-active-sub-modules-in-a-maven-project):

```
mvn --also-make dependency:tree | grep maven-dependency-plugin | awk '{ print $(NF-1) }'
```

But when I try to output that to a file like this :

```
mvn dependency:list -DoutputFile="foo.txt"
```

I see that `foo.txt` is created in each and every sub-module of A, rather than module A(the aggregator). I need one single file with the list of dependencies, from which I can filter out the modules using

```
grep maven-dependency-plugin | awk '{ print $(NF-1) }'
```

So I need two things:
1. output the `dependency:list` or `dependency:tree` in one file for the aggregator, and
2. In the overall project, read both files from modules A and B and have a way to do some comparison and output results (fail the build if comparison gives undesired result).

Any pointers would be helpful.

EDIT:

Clarifying that I need all this to happen during build (`mvn clean install`) of the project, every time it builds.

Answer (score 0):

> 1. output the dependency:list or dependency:tree in one file for the aggregator

Just tweaking the command where you get the list of all the sub-modules for let's say A module, you can save the redirected list of all its submodule to a file as -

```
mvn --also-make dependency:tree | grep maven-dependency-plugin | awk '{ print $(NF-1) }' >> subModuleList.txt
```

> 2. In the overall project, read both files from modules A and B and have a way to do some comparison and output results (fail the build if
>      comparison gives a undesired result).

For the case of comparison assuming you have two text files in hand at this stage namely `subModuleListA.txt` and `subModuleListB.txt`. You can write a *Test* to parse these files and compare their elements. This test should fail for the **undesired result** and hence marking the complete build failure(also getting to log the reason for failure, I expect.)

Comment: How do I add mechanism to generate the txt file during the build? Because want this test to happen every time someone builds the project.