# Generate module diagram of an existing app

Tags: java, maven, graph, uml

I have an exisiting application with many modules that have other modules ..., and I want to know which module is using/ used by other modules.
I checked other questions : [1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9229651/is-it-possible-to-view-a-multi-module-maven-project-in-eclipse-as-a-hierarchy), [2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7074590/how-can-you-display-the-maven-dependency-tree-for-the-plugins-in-your-project), [3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4084669/how-to-generate-a-graph-of-the-dependency-between-all-modules-of-a-maven-project), [4](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3662291/how-to-list-active-sub-modules-in-a-maven-project), [5](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10928930/organize-maven-multi-module-project-in-eclipse) ... but either the solution doesn't work, or the links are broken ...

I also tested some eclipse plugins but none of them gives the wanted result.
can anyone help ? 

**UPDATE** 
I tried this  [tool](https://github.com/ltearno/pom-explorer) and it is working, but it generate a graph of all dependencies in project (slf4j,arquillian ...)

Comment: Hi, just a question, do you need to generate UML model from code or UML diagrams ? Because I do not think that it is possible to generate meaningfull diagram from code.

Comment: I wish just to see relationships between modules of a project, since it is a big project that have a lot of module, I think that it is helpful to generate a component diagram (or anything else) in order to understand project architecture

Comment: Apologize I answered about component before seeing this comment, by module you mean package ?

Comment: What about https://github.com/ferstl/depgraph-maven-plugin

Answer (score 1):

Could this tool be an answer ? [Java reverse engineering](https://wiki.eclipse.org/Java_reverse_engineering)

Comment: Thank you for your response, but I think that this tool is useful if you wish to generate class diagram. however, I need a component diagram in order to understand a project structure

Comment: Component diagrams ? But how your code "defines" a component ? As I know there is no definition about what is a component in code. Maybe you mean artifacts instead component ?

Comment: Ammm, in fact I have a maven project which has many maven modules, (some modules have also other modules ...) so I'm trying to have a component diagram that said that my app X have the following modules  m1,m2,m3...., what I want is a diagram that tells your app have the following modules, and modules m1 uses modules m2 and m3 .....

Comment: So, what i say is not answer and maybe will not help you but anyway. First you need a tool which generates uml model from maven poms ( i do not know if a such tool exists) and then you need to decide if a maven module is a compenent or "one or several" artefacts. For me a maven module is more an artifact than a component.

Comment: A partial definiton of a component: a Component is a modular unit with defined Interfaces that is replaceable within its
environment. The Component concept addresses the area of component-based development and component-based
system, where a Component is modeled throughout the development life cycle and successively refined into
deployment and run-time.
An important aspect of component is the reuse of previously constructed Components. A
Component can be considered an autonomous unit within a system or subsystem. It has provided
and/or required Interfaces, and its internals are hidden.